# What could be the cause of a program crashing without notice?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I have a C++ application that suddenly stops working when I do a certain action (clicking at a button in gtk). I tried debugging it, creating Signal Handlers for SIGTERM, SIGABORT, SIGILL, etc to write a backtrace with the gcc functions, tried to attach a debugger, etc. Nothing. I just do not get any output from anything, the program just vanishes from the memory.

Are there any techniques I have not tried yet? I dont know how to debug this problem.

I forgot to mention: This happens on a Linux system (tried debian and ubuntu). Both with X11 (not wayland)

Comment: Is there an entry in the event viewer - assuming you are on windows?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at the function `abort`. I think there were some others like that. Once a breakpoint is hit you can look at the call stack.

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning this, its Linux. Abort also does not trigger the debugger to stop :(

Comment: enable crash dump, if it creates a dump file after crash then you can explore it with tools like mdb etc.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on exit().

Comment: Start the program in a terminal. Do `echo $?` immediately after the program finished.

Comment: Thats the problem: I cant. (the `echo $?`). The program gets forked by another program (and there is no way to start it properly any other way because it relys on conditions of the parent process)

Comment: Get the exit code in the parent process.

Comment: What is the output of gdb after the program disappears?

Comment: Look at `dmesg` output. Use `strace -f -p <pid>`. Also gdb should output the cause of crash (if it really happens). Are you attaching to a wrong pid number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be:

- A signal. By default, *gdb* stops on error signals, so no custom handler is needed.
- `exit()` function and any other function from exit family (like `_exit`, `_Exit` , etc.). Use `b exit` to set a breakpoint.
- Since it's *c++*, and exception could be thrown. Use `catch throw` to stop when an exception is thrown.
- The last thread exit. `b pthread_exit`.
- Thread cancellation. `b pthread_cancel`.
- `main` function normally reached its end. Use disassembly to set a breakpoint on address.

If all of this doesn't help, attach to your application before the button is pressed, pause it with <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> in *gdb*. Then, press the button (while the window is unresponsive). A gtk application should normally dispatch the event from X11 queue even if it was paused. Do step by step assembly debugging with `ni` and `si`.